# Issues reading string from file with fgetc C (without use fscanf,etc)

Tags: c, realloc, fgetc

I'm trying to read just a string until a space occurs from a file using `fgetc`. I could not use `fscanf` and other i/o functions because I have to know if a line feed is read. A function call `leerString(string,f)` should change the string variable content, it works if I print the string into the function, but at the outside its value is NONE.

I have got some errors like `segmentation faults` and others with the `realloc` function when I try to change the return value with the string variable or pass the "contador" variable like a reference parameter. This is driving me crazy. Sorry the bad english.

```
char leerString(char *string, FILE *archivo){
    char caracter,caracter2 = 0;
    char *nombre = malloc(sizeof(char)*30);//works like a buffer
    int i = 0; 
    int j = 0;
    while (1){
        caracter = fgetc(archivo);
        if ((caracter != 32) && (caracter != EOF) && (caracter != '\n')){ 
            if (i < 30){
                nombre[i] = caracter;
            }
            else{
                nombre = realloc(nombre,30);
                if (nombre != NULL){
                    nombre[i] = caracter;
                }
                else{
                    printf("Error de asignacion de memoria\n");
                    exit(-2); 
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    char *nombre2=malloc(sizeof(char)*i);//allocating the real size of the str
    for (j = 0; j<i; j++){ //cleaning the buffer
        caracter2 = nombre[j];
        nombre2[j] = caracter2;
    }   
    strcpy(string,nombre2);
    return caracter;    
}
```

Comment: First thing your `realloc()` does nothing. Second thing, don't allocate a new buffer just to copy the old one, it doesn't make sense. Also, the `cleaning the buffer` `for` loop, what is it for? weird! And you must post the function where you call `leerString()` from, because the error is very likely there.

Comment: You're using `realloc()` but your buffer remains the same size.  Why bother using `malloc()/realloc()` at all?  (And you need to `free()` the buffer, too.)

Comment: fgetc() returns a int, not a char.   With out defining 'character', etc as an int, cannot check for EOF and (on certain systems like windows/DOS) cannot reliability check for '\n'

Answer (score 2):

I can see a lot of problems with your code

1. You are using `realloc()` to re-allocate a buffer of the same size; it's meant for resizing the buffer.
2. Your `caracter` variable has type `char`, but `fgetc()` returns `int`.
3. You allocate memory for the destination string, you then use `realloc()` unnecessarily as explained above, and then you allocate space again, and do this

   ```
   for (j = 0; j<i; j++){ //cleaning the buffer
       caracter2 = nombre[j];
       nombre2[j] = caracter2;
   }
   ```

   which does nothing more than,

   ```
   memcpy(nombre2, nombre, i);
   ```
4. You did not allocate space for the terminating `nul` byte, so `strcpy()` will fail in your code, causing possible a segmentation fault or anything else, since it's Undefined Behavior.

You should also, be sure that `string` has enough space to copy the characters into it, or just return a pointer to the `malloc()`ed string in your function, which returns `char` and I don't know whether that is useful or not since you didn't post enough code to tell.

A better solution would be

```
char *
leerString(char *string, size_t size, FILE *archivo)
{
    int    chr;
    size_t i;

    i   = 0;
    chr = fgetc(archivo);
    while ((chr != EOF) && (isspace(chr) == 0) && (i < size - 1))
    {
        string[i++] = chr;
        chr         = fgetc(archivo);
    }
    if (i == 0)
        return NULL;
    string[i] = '\0'; /* ensure it's `nul' terminated */

    return string;
}
```

which you can use as follows

```
char string[100];

if (leerString(string, sizeof(string), archivo) != NULL)
    printf("%s\n", string);
```

Comment: returning NULL when EOF encountered, means the last string will not be processed.  suggest modifying the 'if' block to check if 'i' == 0 as a reason to return NULL  in all other cases, terminate the string and return the string ptr

Comment: @user3629249 `EOF` will only be returned in case the user intentionally presses Ctrl+D or Ctrl+Z depending on the console, and in that case `NULL` should be returned indicating that the input was canceled, on the other hand if it's an empty string, it's still input, and there is no way of returning `""` in this function except if `EOF` is returned before any input, so I think it's correct. That is how `fgets()` works I think.

Comment: if the user enters ";lakjdf;lkdfee<ctrl-z> there will be a final string to be handled

Comment: @user3629249 I see your point, and I think you are right. And, I fixed it.